# iOS - How to identify which network is used when both networks(WIFI & CELL)available

Tags: ios, audio-streaming, ios4

I am working on a  iOS Application, which uses the network connection to talk to remote server.

My application provides the statistics count of my application bandwidth utilization of each networks like WIFI - 10.01 MB , Cell - 02.00 MB.

Assume that I am in a place where i have a Cell and WiFi Networks. How to identify which network(Cell or Wifi) used by my application?

I hope i can test it using Reachability API if i have iPhone. I have only iPAD with WiFI. so i could not test it on my own.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html

It should do the trick. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Have you reviewed the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html) class?

> How to identify which network(Cell or Wifi) used by my application?

This is exactly what it does.

Comment: Hi, I have reviewed the [Reachability](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Listings/Classes_Reachability_h.html) class. NetworkStatus enum has 3 possible values(**NotReachable, ReachableViaWiFi, ReachableViaWWAN**). When i have access to both Network,This class does not notify me both **Cell and Wifi** networks are available.

Comment: When Both Network is Available, Is there any chance, one connection uses **Cell Network** and another connection uses **Wifi Network** OR Always __WIFI__ takes the __highest precedence__ in the Data Connection.

Comment: If there is a route to the host through the WiFi, then _I believe_ the iPhone will always use it in preference to the WAN.